# HTML select element phantom padding in Chrome

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/7nudw/2/

The following select element and div should look exactly the same. Somehow the select has both extra horizontal and vertical padding. What did I miss? Thanks.

browsers tesed (chrome version seems to matter):

- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
- Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36

`<select class="test"><option>option 1</option></select>
<br/>
<div class="test">option 1</div>`

```
.test {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: monospace;

    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    padding-left: 0;

    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

[image]

EDIT #1:
http://jsfiddle.net/7nudw/5/
add line-height still doesn't work.

EDIT #2:
works on Mac OS with a newer chrome/webkit build:

- Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53
- could there be a bug fix from 537.36 to 537.51.1?

Comment: take out margin and padding on the option element. won't be 100% but closer

Comment: @albert that won't work I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers often have their own (slightly different) ways of rendering `<select>` elements, which can make it frustrating to get them to appear exactly as desired using only CSS.

In your example, I think Chrome's rendering method is what's leading to the extra horizontal padding. However, the vertical padding can be removed by ensuring the `line-height` in `<select>` is exactly the font size:

```
select{
    line-height:1em;
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nudw/4/) to show that. If you want a `<select>` to look a certain way across all browsers, you may want to consider creating one yourself using JavaScript. (There are just some considerations to take into account when you do that.)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Uh, what browser are you looking at it with? Since this was Chrome-specific, I'm only using Chrome (mine is version 28).

Comment: Chrome and Safari are fine, but OP was complaining about Mozilla where it looks awful

Comment: Oh, I guess the title "HTML select element phantom padding in Chrome" might be a little misleading then...

Comment: @ValentinMercier nvm the mozilla, that's just how the user agent string looks like. The "Webkit" part indicates it is chrome/safari. It does seem to work for chrome on mac and safari, which is extra frustrating.

Comment: On my mac your original code worked FINE on chrome AND safari but not on mozilla. I have everything up to date.

Comment: Added screenshot to clarify what i am talking about.

Comment: I feel if you're looking for a pixel-perfect appearance, it might be a better route to just create a replacement element with HTML, and give it `<select>`-like behaviour using JavaScript. You will be hard-pressed to find a cross-browser solution for extensively styling an element like this.